# Which torrent client has command line arguments to start/stop downloads?

Tags: software-recommendation, command-line, scripts, bittorrent

first of all, I want to create shell script to start/stop downloads in torrent client. I don't need CLI but if you know how I can do that with CLI using shell script then it is okay.

I use jDownloader which is GUI based application but has some command line arguments as below which I use to start/stop download.

```
-h/--help       Show this help message
-a/--add-link(s)    Add links
-co/--add-container(s)  Add containers
-d/--start-download Start download
-D/--stop-download  Stop download
-H/--hide       Don't open Linkgrabber when adding Links
-m/--minimize       Minimize download window
-f/--focus      Get jD to foreground/focus
-s/--show       Show JAC prepared captchas
-t/--train      Train a JAC method
-r/--reconnect      Perform a Reconnect
-C/--captcha <filepath or url> <method> Get code from image using JAntiCaptcha
-p/--add-password(s)    Add passwords
-n --new-instance   Force new instance if another jD is running
```

So I can easily start/stop download as follows,

```
jdownloader --start-download
jdownloader --stop-download
```

now I want torrent client to do that through shell script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [`Flush`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flush/) to start or stop torrent downloads of running instance through terminal.

I can use these options with flush.

```
  --start={all,downloads,uploads}     Start torrents  
  --stop={all,downloads,uploads}      Stop torrents
```

---

### Command line  options for other torrent clients

**1. `Deluge` have very few options**

```
Usage: deluge-gtk [options]

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit

  Common Options:
    -c CONFIG, --config=CONFIG
                        Set the config folder location
    -l LOGFILE, --logfile=LOGFILE
                        Output to designated logfile instead of stdout
    -L LOGLEVEL, --loglevel=LOGLEVEL
                        Set the log level: none, info, warning, error,
                        critical, debug
    -q, --quiet         Sets the log level to 'none', this is the same as `-L
                        none`
```

**2. For `Transmission`**

```
Usage:
  transmission-gtk [OPTION...] [torrent files or urls]

Help Options:
  -h, --help               Show help options
  --help-all               Show all help options
  --help-gtk               Show GTK+ Options

GTK+ Options
  --class=CLASS            Program class as used by the window manager
  --name=NAME              Program name as used by the window manager
  --screen=SCREEN          X screen to use
  --sync                   Make X calls synchronous
  --gtk-module=MODULES     Load additional GTK+ modules
  --g-fatal-warnings       Make all warnings fatal

Application Options:
  -p, --paused             Start with all torrents paused
  --version                Show version number and exit
  -m, --minimized          Start minimized in notification area
  -g, --config-dir         Where to look for configuration files
  --display=DISPLAY        X display to use
```

**3. `qbittorrent` options**

```
Usage:
    qbittorrent --version: displays program version
    qbittorrent --no-splash: disable splash screen
    qbittorrent --help: displays this help message
    qbittorrent --webui-port=x: changes the webui port (current: 8080)
    qbittorrent [files or urls]: downloads the torrents passed by the user (optional)
```

Comment: For Deluge, you need to load **deluge-console** which is a command-line method of controlling the torrent client.

Answer (score 5):

rtorrent, deluge and transmission all have native Linux torrent clients that can be operated via the command line.

Comment: rtorrent is awesome.

Answer (score 3):

utorrent has that capability

here are some resources that may help you gain more info.

https://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?id=53988

http://www.utorrent.com/downloads/linux

Comment: it is utorrent server and it can be controlled with web based UI. It does not have command line argument to start/stop downloads.

Comment: Well thats the best I could find you.

Answer (score 0):

transmission-gtk has the "-p" option, that starts the client with all torrents paused. With no options will start the client with all the torrents downloading.

Answer (score 0):

rTorrent:

- http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/wiki/RTorrentCommonTasks#Startorstopalltorrents
- http://code.google.com/p/pyroscope/wiki/RtControlExamples#Automatic_stop_of_torrents_having_problems
- Anything else you can think of and that can be done via xmlrpc